# How to create try-error class in R

Tags: r, try-catch

I need to return "try-error" class or same class which inherits from it. Is it possible in R?

So, is it possible to create function like this:

```
Foo <- function(x)
{
    if (x != 2) { res <- 1 }
    else { res <- # create object with class type "try-error" and message "I hate 2!"/ }

    return(res);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes are a pretty loose concept in R; you can just assign any class(es) you desire as character strings in the `class` attribute of an object. For example, using the `structure` function:

```
Foo <- function(x) {
    if (x != 2) {
        res <- 1
    } else { 
        res <- structure(
            "message", 
            class = c("try-error", "character")
        )
    }
    res
}

Foo(1)
# [1] 1

Foo(2)
# [1] "message"
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "try-error" "character"

class(Foo(2))
# [1] "try-error" "character"
```

Alternatively, you could use

```
res <- "message"
class(res) <- c("try-error", class(res))
```

in place of `structure`.

It's usually a good idea to *add* new classes rather than completely overwrite the old classes so that method dispatch works reasonably, but depending on your use case this may not be needed or desired.

---

Comment: Thank you! That's all I need!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `try`?

```
Foo <- function(x)
{ res <- try({
    if (x == 2L) stop("I hate 2!", call. = FALSE)
    1
  }) 
  res
}

Foo(2)
#Error : I hate 2!
#[1] "Error : I hate 2!\n"
#attr(,"class")
#[1] "try-error"
#attr(,"condition")
#<simpleError: I hate 2!>
```

I can't see a good reason why you'd create an object of class "try-error" manually.

Comment: The reason of manually object creation could be described this pseudocode example: A <- Foo(x); if (A == 2) { res <- "I hate 2!"; class(res) <- c("try-error", class(res)); } else { res <- 100; } SendSomewhere(res); Foo2(3);

Comment: If you need error handling, use R's facilities for error handling. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: pls, could you give me a good link for reading about error handling in R? Thank you.